# Supplement weight by element or compound

Tags: everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry

When a vitamin or supplement claims, for example, that it contains

> 600 mg of calcium (as calcium carbonate)

what does that mean? Does each tablet contain 600 milligrams of the element calcium?

Or does a tablet contain 600 milligrams of the compound calcium carbonate? In that case, using the molar masses of Ca and CaCO3, each tablet would contain only

600 * (40.1 / 100.1) = 240.4 milligrams of the element calcium.

Comment: It means it has calcium carbonate sufficient to provide 600 mg of calcium. Since chalk is 40% calcium, the mass of chalk is 2.5 times 600 mg = 1.5 g.

Comment: Otherwise, there would be written  "600 mg of calcium carbonate".

Comment: Similarly, 600 Euros ( in dollars ) does not mean 600 dollars, but 600 Euros exchanged into the equivalent number of dollars.